# feature selection using PCA

Tags: pca, feature-selection

is there any way to use PCA for feature selection?! I know what is pca and it is used for dimension reduction.
if you can say no or give me some sources if answer is yes, I would be greatly appreciate it

Comment: You can see how each featuer loads onto the prinicpal components

Comment: Why would you expect it can be used for feature selection?

Comment: @DemetriPananos please, could you explain more?

Comment: See https://juliasilge.com/blog/stack-overflow-pca/

Comment: A closely related concept in the case you want to apply PCA in regression framework is Partial Least Squares regression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression